# Subclass Programmatically Added NSButton?

Tags: objective-c, macos, interface-builder, subclass, nsbutton

I have a bunch of programmatically created NSButtons in my app. How can I go about setting the subclass of these NSButtons without using Interface Builder?

Comment: Do you mean subview? Or do you have some custom `NSButton` subclass that you want to subclass again? Or do you want to instantiate a custom `NSButton` subclass?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create the button, don't create them as NSButtons, create them as your subclass. For example, if you had a subclass of `NSButton` called `MyButton`, instead of something like:

```
NSButton *button = [[NSButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

You would have something like:

```
MyButton *button = [[MyButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
```

This way `button` will be an instance of `MyButton`.